# Bitnami with Adminer on EC2 - how to increase the max_upload_size

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, bitnami, adminer

I'm running an EC2 instance with Bitnami Wordpress AMI and adminer.php to manage the Databases.

When launching adminer.php on my IP it shows me that I have an upload limit of 40mb. I'd like to increase that, but have no idea how.

What I tried so far is updating the `stack/php/etc/php.ini` on the server with `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize from 40 to 120 MB and restarting the apache server with`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache```

But also then the adminer.php script still shows 40MB.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

you also need to restart the PHP-FPM service.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm
```

You shouldn't get that message anymore. For more information, you can check [this Bitnami community post](https://community.bitnami.com/t/cant-upload-big-size-files-5mb-http-error/69562)